# Angularjs: angular-phonecat tutorial app fails first unit test

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine

Just starting to learn Angularjs & unit-testing with jasmine...

Following tutorial on http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02 to find that the very first unit test (which should pass because `scope.phones.length` is 3) fails.

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.2 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 30.0.1599 (Mac OS X 10.8.5)]: Connected on socket BdjA1lVT9OOo8kgQKLYs
Chrome 30.0.1599 (Mac OS X 10.8.5) PhoneCat controllers PhoneListCtrl should create "phones" model with 3 phones FAILED
    ReferenceError: PhoneListCtrl is not defined
        at null.<anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/angular-phonecat/test/unit/controllersSpec.js:12:22)
Chrome 30.0.1599 (Mac OS X 10.8.5): Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED) (0.37 secs / 0.033 secs)
```

So basically, it is stating that PhoneListCtrl is not defined. However the app is working perfectly, and I don't really know where to start considering I am at the beginning of the tutorial!

Here is my unit test which is the default from the tutorial.

**test/unit/controllerSpec.js**

```
'use strict';

/* jasmine specs for controllers go here */
describe('PhoneCat controllers', function() {

  describe('PhoneListCtrl', function(){

    beforeEach(module('phonecatApp'));

    it('should create "phones" model with 3 phones', function() {
      var scope = {},
          ctrl = new PhoneListCtrl(scope);

      expect(scope.phones.length).toBe(3);
    });

    it('should create "phones" model with 3 phones', inject(function($controller) {
      var scope = {},
          ctrl = $controller('PhoneListCtrl', {$scope:scope});

      expect(scope.phones.length).toBe(3);
    }));

  });
});
```

**app/js/controller.js**

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function PhoneListCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.phones = [
    {'name': 'Nexus S',
     'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'},
    {'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'},
    {'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'}
  ];
  $scope.hello = "Hello World";
});
```

config/karma.conf.js http://pastebin.com/PPWjSmyJ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 unit tests in the example (2 `it` blocks). They look like they are supposed to do the same thing, but only the second actually creates your controller.

When you defined the controller in angular, it is not a globally available object that you can initialise with `new Controller(...)`. You must request it from angular.

Your second test (which seems to be passing) does this by injecting the `$controller` service which will do perform any actions needed to set up and request the controller.

```
inject(function($controller) { ... });
```

It then creates the controller using this service like so

```
var scope = {},
    ctrl = $controller('PhoneListCtrl', {$scope:scope});
```

In your first test you try to just use the `PhoneListCtrl` variable directly. As the error says, this doesn't exist unless you define a variable with that name in your function.

---

I have just noticed that failing test in the tutorial. This is specifically for if you have defined a controller on the global namespace. For example

```
function PhoneListCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.phones = [
    {'name': 'Nexus S',
     'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'},
    {'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'},
    {'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'}
  ];
  $scope.hello = "Hello World";
};
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', PhoneListCtrl);
```

The test would then work because you have function defined globally that is used as a controller, so you are able to test it without paying attention to the fact it is a controller. This means if you try to use other services you will have to inject them yourself and perform any actions that `$controller` would do for you.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. So if I understand correctly, the first test is correctly failing because, because `PhoneListCtrl` is namespaced. The first test looks for PhoneListCtrl in the global namespace.

Comment: Correct. The first test treats `PhoneListCtrl` as just a javascript variable that was defined at a global level (i.e. not inside another function). Your code defines the controller function inside the parameter when registering it as a controller. So it never gets left in the global namespace.

Comment: Where are the docs for `inject`? AFAICT, that function doesn't actually exist.

Comment: Current docs are at http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.mock.inject. the function is published at both `angular.mock.inject` and on window as `inject`.